# Why does my reference update the element array it is referencing?

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

Could anyone explain to me in layman's terms why my reference is updating the element array that it is referencing? I thought the whole point of a reference was to only reference a value.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int arr[4] = { 0,0,0,0 };
    arr[0] = 1;

    int& reference = arr[0];
    reference = 2;

    std::cout << arr[0];

}
```

Comment: You are describing the very purpose of a reference.  What you do to `reference`, you do to `arr[0]`.

Comment: Are you confusing `int&` with `const int&` where the latter is read-only since you cannot assign a new value to the referred-to int? Otherwise this acts exactly as intended and is the designed purpose of references, you are modifying the referred-to value, not a *copy* of the value. I'm not sure I understand what you expected to occur.

Comment: if you only want to reference a value without being able to modify it then use a const reference. What you are doing here is exactly what a reference should do

Comment: What do you mean by _referencing a value_? What is _a value_?

Comment: You are expecting a C++ reference to behave like a Java reference. That’s _not_ how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In layman terms, as requested:

References and pointers are basically the same thing, the main difference being that references cannot be `null` and simplified syntax when you work with them.

Also, array variables are also pointers. `arr` is a pointer to the beginning of the array, `arr[1]` is the pointer to the second element, it is the same thing as `arr + 1`.

When you do `int& reference = arr[0]`, you assign your `reference` to point at the first element of your array. When you then call `reference = 2` it means the same as if you did `arr[0]=2` or

```
int * pointer = arr + 0;
*pointer = 2;
```

Comment: Thank you Aivean, I guess my basic understanding of a reference was wrong.

Thinking of them as a pointer makes this much simpler.

Comment: "*References and pointers are basically the same thing*" - from a language standpoint, they are very different things. A reference is just an alias to an object, while a pointer is a distinct object holding a memory address as its value. From an implementation standpoint, references are commonly implemented using pointers, but that is not a requirement. "*array variables are also pointers*" - no, they are not. An array is a distinct type. But, an array can *decay* into a pointer to its 1st element in *certain* contexts.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you're, of course, correct. But I didn't want to recite the whole "Philosophy of C++" in the answer that asked specifically for layman terms. Instead I tried to convey the simple intuition that, I believe, could help a beginner to alleviate the confusion about the references. Cheers!